# how can I scroll my JFrame using the JScrollbar?

Tags: java, scrollbar, jframe

I have a problem.

I have a JFrame with some JTextFields, JLabels, Jlists & JButtons now the contents of my frame is more than the screen area so I want to attach a JScrollBar to my JFrame but my srollbar does not work. So, can anyone please guide me on how I can scroll my JFrame using the JScrollbar?

Comment: are you want to Scroll with JScrollPane to some directions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Put all the components in one panel (instead of in the JFrame)
2. Add this panel to a JScrollPane
3. Add the JScrollPane to your frame.

I should be something like:

```
JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.add(panel1);
container.add(Panel2);
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(container);
frame.add(jsp);
```

Comment: 2. Add this panel to a JScrollPane

Comment: Thank you for very quick response. You wrote 2.Add this panel to a JScrollBar BUT in the code you add it to JScrollPane.

Comment: But JScrollBar is not used for this purpose?

Comment: It id, as part of JScrollPane

Comment: The JScrollBar will appear automagically if you set things up the way MByD described.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the layout you are using with your JFrame. If you want to add working scrollbar to your panel you should look at the [`JScrollPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) class and the [`Scrollable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html) interface which must be implemented by scrollable components.

The *How to use scroll panes* chapter in the swing tutorial may also be an interesting reading: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: I use com.jgoodies.forms.layout.FormLayout. How can I adjust scrolling to this layout?