# Java: JFrame resolution?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resolution, layout-manager

I made a program using several JFrames on a Mac, and the resolution was okay, everything fit the screen properly. But when I run the program on my PC the JFrames are way too large and go right off the screen.

My question is: Is it possible to set the universal resolution on a JFrame so that all the components are drawn a little smaller? I would rather do that then go through the entire program and resize every component manually.

Comment: *"I made a program using several JFrames.."*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)
*"Is it possible to set the universal resolution on a JFrame so that all the components are drawn a little smaller?"* I hope not!  Having a GUI on my screen where the text is 'too small' (read 'smaller than standard') would be of no use to me.  Use layouts to make a compact (e.g. `CardLayout`) & resizable GUI.  If all else fails, drop the content pane into a scroll-pane (but the situation would have to be dire to justify that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I made a program using several JFrames

wrong use CardLayout instead, only if is there real reason use JDialog or JOptionPane with parent and (JDialog) maybe with setModal(true) to the single JFrame

> But when I run the program on my PC the JFrames are way too large and go right off the screen

- are you using AbsoluteLayout
- is your PC somehow specific
- every Native OS returns different (f[or example there you cann't find out two containers with the same pixels ratio on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371443/714968)) Font and default Size for JComponents

> Is it possible to set the universal resolution on a JFrame so that all the components are drawn a little smaller?

use proper LayoutManager, sure not easy job, required real effort

> I would rather do that then go through the entire program and resize every component manually.

use proper LayoutManager,

- for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated your issue with different screen size betweens PC's or platforms

Comment: Thank you! I think you misunderstood what I meant by 'multiple JFrames' though. I just meant that the entire program involves more than one, they don't all show up at once though :P I am using absolute layout, so I'll fiddle around with the layouts that have been recommended and see what I can do to fix my problem.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can't change the resolution of Swing components. But you can get the current screen size from the system ([here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/screen_ScreenSize.html)'s an example). With this screen size you can adjust your components.

If you are coding your GUI wisely, you wouldn't have to resize all your components of your GUI manually. Instead, a top-level JPanel (or JFrame or what ever) will adjust its size due to its contained components (e.g. with something like pack()). So only a few components will have a hard coded size. This size could also be externalized into a class or a file that is easy to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a problem like your's and I solved it with a JScrollbar! 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928514/how-can-i-scroll-my-jframe-using-the-jscrollbar) is how to make your JFrame scrollable.