# Scroll bar not working for JTextArea, why?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a scrollable text area, (much like the one i'm writing in right now as in stack overflow's one). It seems as if the scrollpane and the text area are mutually exclusive and i'd like to create a connection between them

```
package Notepad;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

public class test {

    private JFrame frame;
    private Font f = new Font(null);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test window = new test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public test() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));


        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setFont(f.deriveFont(40f));


        JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollBar, BorderLayout.EAST);



    }

}
```

Comment: See [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) or [how can I scroll my JFrame using the JScrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928514/how-can-i-scroll-my-jframe-using-the-jscrollbar)

Comment: Still having trouble understanding it. Thank you. I'll continue trying with the links above. @Obicere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `JScrollPane` rather than `JScrollBar`

Wrong:

```
    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
```

Right:

```
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textArea);
```

you can set the size of this ScrollPane like so:

```
    Dimension size = new Dimension (0, 50);
    scroller.setPreferredSize(size);
```

**NOTE**: When you use `JScrollPanes`, be sure to put where you want it in parentheses, or it will not show up.

Answer (score 1):

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setFont(f.deriveFont(40f));

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG sorry guys. I imported JScrollBar not JScrollPane. Thank you all. I'm going to test this fix and get back to you.

Edit:

It works. Thank you guys!!!